# Entitiy spawn on Button press

Tags: java, 2d

I'm trying to create a little 2D-Zombie-Shoot game. I'm pretty much at the beginning of programming. At least, I can create a player that is moving with arrow keys and stuff. My question is: How do I spawn a Zombie on a button-press? I've already tried it, but with no good results. Here's the code:

```
//A variable, for the amount of zombies spawned
public int zombie = 0;


 public void tick() {
 //The rest of the code is irrelevant
 ...........

    if (mouse1.isPressed()) {
        zombie++;
    }

}

public void render() {
    //The rest of the code is irrelevant
    ...........

    //Player
    g.drawImage(playerImage, x, y, null);

    //Check how many zombies should be created
    if (zombie > 0) {
        g.drawImage(zombieImage, zX, zY, null);
    }
    ...........
```

Comment: With your current code you'll only ever see one zombie. You need a separate 'x' and 'y' value for each in order to draw them in different locations.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a zombie `class`.

```
public class Zombie {
public int x, y;

public Entity(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void tick() {
//code to control movement and such
    }

public void render() {
    g.drawImage(zombieImage, x, y, null);
}
}
```

I'm not sure which class you are showing in your code but you will need to make a zombie `ArrayList` for your zombies in it.

```
protected List<Zombie> zombies = new ArrayList<Zombie>();
```

In your tick method you should call all of the zombie's tick methods like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++) {
            zombies.get(i).tick();
        }
```

You also need a similar thing in render

```
for (int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++) {
            zombies.get(i).render();
        }
```

This will allow you to have multiple zombies, in order to add new zombies, you call `zombies.add(new Zombie(`your x value you want`,` your y value you want`);`

In order to remove zombies you call `zombies.remove(`the index of the zombie to remove`);`

If you just do this, you will need to know to know the index of the zombie to remove. To get around this you could have a `boolean` called removed inside of the `Zombie` `class`.
You can then cycle through the `ArrayList` as earlier and simply remove the zombies that have the `removed` variable equal to `true` like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++) {
            if (zombies.get(i).removed) zombies.remove(i);
        }
```

This will allow you to have multiple zombies and have them all render and update simultaneously.